# Installing PEAR on Mac 10.6.8

Tags: pear

I'm trying to install PEAR so that I can use the build tool Phing and I can't get the 'pear' command to work. Has anyone done this before?

I went to [this link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) to install PEAR on Mac. I installed wget fine and ran the first line:

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

Then, I ran the second line in the terminal, and it seems PEAR installed fine. However, if I just type in pear, it says 'command not found'.

Anyone have any idea on installing PEAR?

Answer (score 0):

The `go-pear.phar` installer asked you for the PEAR path locations (for php files, data files, script files etc).

The `pear` command got installed in the `bin`/script directory. Add the full path of that directory to your `$PATH` variable, and pear will be executable:

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/path/to/my/pear/bin/dir
$ pear version
1.9.4
```